# MongoDb: How to build realtime subscription based notification system

Tags: c++, mongodb, push-notification

**Problem**

I am building a subscription based software system, which provides notification feed based on provided query when results of the query change because of documents changed by add/remove/update. For example,

1. subscribe

   ```
   void mySystem.subscribe(collection, QUERY("name" << "abc"), callBack);
   ```

   where callback is defined as:

   ```
   void Client::Callback(ChangedDocuments, Operation)
   {
       // handle the change
   }
   ```
2. if someone calls `mySystem.Add(collection, documentsNameIsAbc)`, the callback will be called, so that the subscribing clients are notified of changes.

This needs to be done as fast as possible, so something like scanning redo log will not work for me.

**Possibilities**

a) A naive way would be remember results of all queries, after each add/remove/update, run all queries again, and then send diffs as notification.

b) A bit smarter way would be take the changing document(before any db operation), check whether it 'matches' any query. If so, send notification. However, sounds like this kind of 'match' is not supported.

c) Take query is in regex format, serialize the changing document to json format, and run regex match.

I am using C++, although the problem sounds language neutral.

Any inputs are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you're language-agnostic, you may want to take a look at the [meteor](/questions/tagged/meteor) framework. It implements oplog tailing, and coincidentally a new version was released yesterday that focuses precisely on that:

[Meteor 0.7.1: oplog support for complex queries / scaling Meteor using oplog tailing](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/02/24/meteor-071-oplog-support-for-complex-queries-meteor-developer-accounts)

Comment: Thanks Dan. Took a look at the video, sounds pretty cool. Will dig further.

Comment: "Meteor's DDP implementation handles the rest. It intelligently polls your database to pick up changes and push them down to the client." looks like they took a) approach. from: https://www.meteor.com/#blog/2012/03/21/introducing-ddp